# How to increase Docker System Disk

Tags: docker

while running the docker file, I got an error: no space left on device, its capacity is only 144 MB, it filled with 6 steps of docker file, now I want to increase the docker system space, please help me out of this [image desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKtCX.png)

[image]

Comment: This limit is not related to a container. You didn't even start one yet. You have no space left in your system's `/proc/kcore` location.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of space on the device. If you have lots of images and want to remove them, you can use [rhis](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes.amp)
`sudo docker image ls`
To see local images and their sizes. and this to remove them:
`docker images purge`

Checkout the link so you don't remove something you need to keep accidentally.